# Is it possible to capture an iframe window before load is completed?

Tags: javascript

Is there an event I can listen to to capture the iframe's window object as soon as the iframe loads, and before any javascript running in the iframe gets processed?

To answer "why would you want to do that?" I'll provide some context: I'm building a [web-based IDE](https://theia-ide.org) extension to add a Javascript console that is bound to a web preview iframe. The extension overrides the `console.*` functions to route them back to a custom console in the IDE instead of the native browser console.

The custom console is currently listening for the iframe's `load` event, and binding itself (ie, overriding `window.console`) then. The problem is, that doesn't capture console messages that get logged before the page is finished loading as the `load` event only gets fired *after* the page has loaded.

Comment: You could try "overriding" `console.log`. But I may not be understanding your requirements exactly.

Comment: Already doing that part. The thing I'm trying to figure out is overriding it at the right _time_, before anything else on the page loads.

Comment: Could you override in the head section before any other scripts are called, and force any other included scripts to not use cache via a random `?` parameter? Within the context of the iframe?

Comment: I may be able to inject server side as a last resort, but was hoping to keep the code in the preview unmodified.

Comment: I always looked at console.log as being sequential. So in your case, possibly, override it *twice*. Once at the very beginning before other scripts load (and execute), and once again on the load event? Where the 1st override serves to "buffer" those results while loading the page.